# Angular 2 - How to pass "checked" attribute to child in template?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I have a custom directive `<foo checked></foo>`. In the template of `foo` I have `<input type="checkbox">`. If `checked` is on `foo`, I want to have `<input type="checkbox" checked>`. I have not yet seen how to handle these attributes which do not have values, detect them, and mark child elements with them if they are present.

Help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following:

Here is a plunker as well: https://plnkr.co/edit/1JTijgHGvIGYMpDYC2i8?p=preview

```
import {Component,Attribute} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" [checked]="isChecked">
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class Child { 
  isChecked;
  constructor(@Attribute("checked") checked) {
    this.isChecked = !(checked === null);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app', 
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <child checked></child>
      <child></child>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [Child]
})
export class App {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think as per your requirement, in your directive constructor you can have :-

Foo directive -

```
import {Directive, Attribute} from 'angular2/core';
@Directive({
    selector:   'foo'
})
export class foo {
     constructor(@Attribute('checked') checked: string) {
            if (checked === null){
              //checked is not present
            }else{
              //checked is present
            }
...
    }
....
}
```

and, you can use -

```
<foo checked></foo>
```